# tikzpicture & chemfig, create line above of Double bond

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig

I'm trying to combine `tikzpicture` and `chemfig`, but I don't understand how to do this:

[image: What i'm trying to do, but failure with]

As you can see, it's not what it should be by the following code:

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw [line width=0.25mm, red ] (1.5,0.3) -- (2,1.25) node [right] {negativer Schwerpunkt};;
 \chemfig{C(-[3]@{a}H)(-[5]H)=C(-[1]@{b}H)(-[7]H)} \qquad + \qquad \chemfig{\lewis{246,Br}-\lewis{026,Br}} \qquad $\xlongrightarrow{\text{\qquad}}$ \qquad \chemfig{C(-[3]H)(-[5]H)=C(-[1]H)(-[7]H)} \qquad + \qquad \chemfig{\lewis{246,Br}-\lewis{026,Br}}
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

(The `\qquad` and `+` are ignored...)

Full Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{extarrows}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\geometry{verbose,a4paper,tmargin=25mm,bmargin=25mm,lmargin=25mm,rmargin=15mm}
\newcommand\namebond[4][5pt]{\chemmove{\path(#2)--(#3)node[midway,sloped,yshift=#1]{#4};}}

\begin{document}
\section*{Organische Chemie}
\begin{flushleft}
Die organische Chemie (auch Organik genannt) beschreibt ein Teilgebiet der Chemie, in dem die chemischen Verbindungen behandelt werden, welche auf Kohlenstoff basieren. Ausnahmen bilden einige anorganische Kohlenstoffverbindungen, sowie der elementare Kohlenstoff. Unter anderem behandelt die organische Chemie die Alkane, Alkene und die Alkine.
\end{flushleft}

\subsection*{Alkane}

\begin{flushleft}
Die Alkane haben die Eigenschaft, Verbindungen von Kohlenstoff und Wasserstoff zu sein, wobei ausschlaggebend ist, dass zwischen den Kohlenstoffen jeweils nur eine einfache Elektronenpaarbindung ist. Es gibt viele verschiedene Alkane, welche häufig auch einen wichtigen Nutzen in unserer Gesellschaft haben. Sie dienen uns als Verbrennungsgase in beispielsweise Campingbrennern.
\end{flushleft}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
CH\textsubscript{4} & Methan & \chemfig{C(-[2]H)(-[4]H)(-[6]H)(-[8]H)}
\cr
\cr
C\textsubscript{2}H\textsubscript{6} & Ethan & \chemfig{C(-[2]H)(-[4]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-H} 
\cr
\cr
C\textsubscript{3}H\textsubscript{8} & Propan & \chemfig{C(-[2]H)(-[4]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-H} 
\end{tabular}\\

Allgemein: C\textsubscript{n}H\textsubscript{2n+2}
\begin{flushleft}
Diese Alkanketten können ziemlich lange sein und ab C\textsubscript{4}H\textsubscript{10} lassen sich sogenannte Isomere finden. Isomere sind allgemein Verbindungen mit der gleichen Summenformel und unterschiedlichen Strukturen. C4H10 könnte also zwei Strukturen haben:
\end{flushleft}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
\chemfig{C(-[2]H)(-[4]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-H} & \chemfig{C(-[2]H)(-[4]H)(-[6]H)--C(-[2]H)(-[6]C(-[4]H)(-[6]H)(-[8]H))--C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-H}
\cr
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Butan (C\textsubscript{4}H\textsubscript{10})} &     \multicolumn{1}{c}{Isobutan/2-Methylpropan (C\textsubscript{4}H\textsubscript{10})}

\end{tabular}\\

\begin{flushleft}
Die Alkane mit eher kürzeren Kettenlängen (bis Butan) sind alle bei Raumtemperatur gasförmig und somit gut als Verbrennungsgase in flüssiger Form, unter Druck gesetzt, in Camping- oder Bunsenbrenner zu gebrauchen. Je länger die Kette wird, desto weniger flüchtig ist das Alkan.
\end{flushleft}

\subsubsection*{Radikale Substitution}

\begin{flushleft}
Radikale sind Moleküle oder Atome, welche einzelne, ungepaarte Elektronen besitzen, weshalb sie sehr reaktiv sind. Bei der radikalischen Substitution (Substitution = Ersetzen) reagiert ein Alkan mit einem Halogen in einer mehrstufigen Reaktion zu einem Halogenalkan. Das ganze beginnt dadurch, dass zuerst die Radikale entstehen müssen. Dies kann beispielsweise durch Licht passieren, welches es schafft, die Bindung zwischen zwei Atomen zu trennen (beispielsweise von Cl2). Betrachtet man die ganze mehrstufige Reaktion, lässt diese sich folgendermassen in Teilreaktionen darstellen:
\end{flushleft}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
Startreaktion: & \chemfig{\lewis{246,Cl}-\lewis{026,Cl}}
\cr
\cr
Kettenreaktion: & \chemfig{\lewis{2460., Cl}} \qquad + \qquad \chemfig{C(-[2]H)(-[4]H)(-[6]H)(-[8]H)} \qquad $\xlongrightarrow{\text{\qquad}}$ \qquad     \chemfig{\lewis{246, Cl}-H} \qquad + \qquad \chemfig{\lewis{4.,C}(-[2]H)(-[6]H)(-[8]H)}\\ \cr & \chemfig{\lewis{0.,C}(-[2]H)(-[4]H)(-[6]H)} \qquad + \qquad     \chemfig{\lewis{246,Cl}-\lewis{026,Cl}} \qquad $\xlongrightarrow{\text{\qquad}}$     \qquad \chemfig{C(-[2]H)(-[4]H)(-[6]H)(-[8]\lewis{026,Cl})} \qquad + \qquad   \chemfig{\lewis{024.6,Cl}}\\ \cr & \chemfig{\lewis{0.246,Cl}} \qquad + \qquad \chemfig{C(-[2]H)(-[4]H)(-[6]H)(-[8]H)} \qquad $\xlongrightarrow{\text{\qquad}}$ \qquad etc...
\cr
\cr
Abbruchreaktion: & \chemfig{\lewis{0.,C}(-[2]H)(-[4]H)(-[6]H)} \qquad + \qquad \chemfig{\lewis{024.6,Cl}} \qquad $\xlongrightarrow{\text{\qquad}}$ \qquad \chemfig{C(-[2]H)(-[4]H)(-[6]H)(-[8]\lewis{026,Cl})}\\ \cr & \chemfig{\lewis{0.,C}(-[2]H)(-[4]H)(-[6]H)} \qquad + \qquad \chemfig{\lewis{4.,C}(-[2]H)(-[6]H)(-[8]H)} \qquad $\xlongrightarrow{\text{\qquad}}$ \qquad \chemfig{C(-[2]H)(-[4]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)(-[8]H)} \\ \cr & \chemfig{\lewis{0.246,Cl}} \qquad + \qquad \chemfig{\lewis{024.6,Cl}} \qquad $\xlongrightarrow{\text{\qquad}}$ \qquad \chemfig{\lewis{246,Cl}-\lewis{026,Cl}}
\end{tabular}

\newpage
\subsubsection*{Nomenklatur}
\newpage
\subsection*{Alkene und Alkine}
\begin{flushleft}
Alkene sind Kohlenwasserstoffe, die im Gegensatz zu den Alkanen zwischen zwei C-Atomen eine Doppelbindung haben. Im Gegensatz zu den Alkanen sind die Alkenen ein wenig reaktiver, so dass diese unter anderem die elektrophile Addition durchführen.
Beispiele:
\end{flushleft}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
Ethen & \chemfig{C(-[3]H)(-[5]H)=C(-[1]H)(-[7]H)} 
\cr
\cr
Propen & \chemfig{C(-[3]H)(-[5]H)=C(-[2]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)(-[8]H)}
\cr
\cr
1-Buten & \chemfig{C(-[3]H)(-[5]H)=C(-[2]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)(-[8]H)}
\cr
\cr
2-Buten & \chemfig{C(-[3]H)(-[5]H)-C(-[2]H)=C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)(-[8]H)}
\end{tabular}
\begin{flushleft}
Alkine sind, wie zu vermuten, Kohlenwasserstoffe mit einer Dreifachbindung zwischen zwei C-Atomen.
Beispiele:
\end{flushleft}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
Ethin (Acetylen) & \chemfig{C(-[4]H)~C(-[8]H)}
\cr
\cr
4-Methyl-2-Hexin & \chemfig{C(-[2]H)(-[4]H)(-[6]H)-C~C-C(-[2]C(-[2]H)(-[4]H)(-[8]H))(-[6]H)--C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)(-[8]H)}
\end{tabular}

\begin{flushleft}
Alkine sind durch die Dreifachbindung sehr energiereich und dadurch instabil. Sie lassen sich dadurch in einer sehr heissen Flamme sehr gut verbrennen, weshalb beispielsweise Ethin in Schweissbrennern, zusammen mit Sauerstoff verwendet wird.
\end{flushleft}

\subsubsection*{Elektrophile Addition}
\begin{flushleft}
Wie bei den Alkanen durch die radikale Substitution kann auch bei den Alkenen eine Reaktion mit Alkanen stattfinden. Diese wird jedoch nicht durch ein Radikal gestartet, sondern durch die Doppelbindung, welche einen negativ partial geladenen Schwerpunkt darstellt. Kommt nun beispielsweise ein Brommolekül in die Nähe, ist dieser negative Schwerpunkt genug stark, dass er die Ladungen im Brommolekül verschieben kann, indem er die Elektronen des Brommoleküls abstösst. Diese sogenannte Polarisierung geht soweit, dass das eine Bromatom abgestossen wird. Die Doppelbindung ist sozusagen die Schwäche der Alkene, was sie zur funktionellen Gruppe der Alkene macht. Der Name elektrophile Addition kommt daher, dass sich Brom zum Ethen addiert. Elektrophil daher, dass Brom sich durch den negativen Schwerpunkt beeinflussen lässt.
\end{flushleft}
\vspace{9mm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [line width=0.25mm, red ] (1.5,0.3) -- (2,1.25) node [right] {negativer Schwerpunkt};;
\chemfig{C(-[3]@{a}H)(-[5]H)=C(-[1]@{b}H)(-[7]H)} \qquad + \qquad \chemfig{\lewis{246,Br}-\lewis{026,Br}} \qquad $\xlongrightarrow{\text{\qquad}}$ \qquad \chemfig{C(-[3]H)(-[5]H)=C(-[1]H)(-[7]H)} \qquad + \qquad \chemfig{\lewis{246,Br}-\lewis{026,Br}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace{5mm}



%\namebond{a}{b}{\scriptsize{negativer Schwerpunkt}}
%\medskip



\begin{flushleft}
Die elektrophile Addition lässt sich auch anhand von Ethen und Wasser darstellen:
\end{flushleft}

\chemfig{C(-[3]H)(-[5]H)=C(-[1]H)(-[7]H)} \qquad + \qquad \chemfig{H-\lewis{26,O}-H} \qquad $\xlongrightarrow{\text{\qquad}}$ \qquad 



\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, be so gentle, to include a complete working example (MWE) from `\documentclass` till `\end{document}`.  It helps us, to help you.

Comment: I don't think you'll understand much, because it's german, but this isn't the important part:P

Comment: What Jan means is to make your code compilable so that we can just copy and paste into our editors to reproduce your problem. See http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that. There's no need to include your text in German if it has no relevance to the problem

Comment: I think you are right, I won't understand much of the content.  Not because its german (I am german too :-)), but because, I am an engineer and have no idea of chemistry.  Nevertheless, as long as I can't copy your example into my editor and have it running, I won't be apt to copy it in order to help you.

Comment: If just included the whole code in the main post.

Comment: @KillTrot that is not the definition of MINIMAL, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rather use `chemfig`'s powerful scheme macros for the actual scheme and use TikZ with `chemfig`'s `\chemmove` (a shortcut for a `tikzpicture` with options `remember picture` and `overlay`) to add the descriptive part. Inside `\chemmove` you can refer to the nodes you mark in the scheme using `chemfig`'s `@{...}` syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\schemestart
  \chemfig{C(-[3]H)(-[-3]H)=[@{b}]C(-[1]H)-[-1]H}
  \+
  \chemfig{\lewis{246,Br}-\lewis{026,Br}}
  \arrow
  \chemfig{C(-[3]H)(-[-3]H)=C(-[1]H)-[-1]H}
  \+
  \chemfig{\lewis{246,Br}-\lewis{026,Br}}
\schemestop
\chemmove{
  \draw[<-,red,shorten <=5pt] (b) --++(0,1)
    node[above] {negativer Schwerpunkt} ;
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the text `negativer Schwerpunkt` left-aligned with the ethylene at the left you can replace the `\chemmove{...}` part with

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \draw[red] (c1.north west) ++(0,.5)
    node[anchor=west,inner sep=0] (text) {negativer Schwerpunkt} ;
  \draw[red,->,shorten >=5pt] (text) -- (b) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Please have a look at `chemfig`'s manual where the scheme commands and `\schemedebug` and the node naming of the several parts are described in order to understand where the `c1` node comes from.

Comment: Totally fine with that, thanks alot

Edit:
\arrow seems not to work for me

Comment: Nevermind, got it working.
May you help me, make it left bounded with the formula?

Edit: Again, i've got it myself. Thanks for the help sir:)

Comment: The Ethylene. Sorry, i meant aligned

Comment: For me it's ok, as it is now.
Thanks anyways, you're work is done:P

Comment: @KillTrot have a look at the edited answer